# Customizing built-in widgets with wtforms ans jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Is possible to change the built-in widgets html output using WTForms and Jinja2?

I want to change the form fields for an xisting Jinja2 template.

The template has a {{ form.my_field }} for a StringField.

I want it to output  instead of the built-in widget, without changing the template.

Comment: So why don't you change your widget? You can pass it to the constructor... http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.__init__

Comment: Then I need to change all The existing forms. I want to have a way to change the widgets without changing the existing code. Currently I have a macro file that includes the widget set macros, but all the templates need to use that macro. I can replace the widgets.core from the wtfforms, but that'll be dirty.

Comment: Where does your "dirty" boundary go? It seems you're calling that dirty, but changing built-in widgets isn't dirty...  For what it's worth you can change the widget at class level and just fix your imports then, without having to replace anything in wtforms.widgets module